# Next/Previous Url only

Tags: codex

I only want to get the URL of the next/previous post link instead of title+link.

I searched WP's codex but unfortunately, I couldn't find it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no functions for that in WordPress core (yet), however, you can:

- Use [`get_previous_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/) to get the previous post.
- Use [`get_next_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_next_post/) to get the next post.
- Or you can also make a direct call to [`get_adjacent_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/) which is used by the above functions.

And then just use `get_permalink()` to get the previous/next post's URL.

For example:

```php
$post = get_post(); // get the current post

$next_post     = get_next_post();     // or use get_adjacent_post( false, '', false, 'category' );
$next_post_url = $next_post ? get_permalink( $next_post ) : '';

$prev_post     = get_previous_post(); // or use get_adjacent_post( false, '', true, 'category' );
$prev_post_url = $prev_post ? get_permalink( $prev_post ) : '';
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it out.

Comment: So, did it work for you 

Comment: sorry for getting back to you late! Yes. It worked. Thanks! :)